# Implement a keyboard buffer in C given a keyboard event

Tags: c, io, keyboard, buffer

I have a C program that detects keyboard events, but I need to know the best technique to implement an input buffer and a simple `getch` function to retrieve the oldest character in the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).  You create a fixed sized array and have two indices, a read index and a write index.  Each time a keyboard event fires, you place the value at the write index and increment.  When the `getch` function is called, you read from the read index and increment it.  If either index goes over the size of the array, it gets reset to the beginning.

If the read index and the write index are equal, there are no keys waiting. If the write index is just before the read index, the buffer is full and keyboard events need to be dropped.

If you don't want a "full" buffer it gets more complicated.